# How to wrap all elements after 4th

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need jQuery script which wraps all elements after 4th `li` with a `div` with class `wrapper`. The number of elements after the 4th `li` isn't fixed, it could be 10 or 5.

Could you please help me with this? Thanks!

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: While it's technically possible to wrap elements like that, it won't work in this case as the HTML you're looking to generate is completely invalid; a `div` cannot be a child of a `ul` and `li` cannot be a child of a `div`. You'll need to think of another way to group those `li` elements.

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan is saying you cannot have a div inside a list (`<ul>` tag). Try to create a separate list (`<ul>`) for the rest of the `<li>` elements.

Comment: Thank guys, so in this case how to make from 1 list 2 separate after 4th element?

Comment: I think you should rethink this structure. How are you getting the data for the li-elements after the 4th? Are they coming dynamically?

Comment: Is your intention just to style them differently after the 4th element? If so :nth-child is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes they coming dynamically and I cannot change structure. I need to hide elements after 4th and add button to show them after click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var lis = $("ul li");
lis.slice(4).wrapAll("<li class='wrapper'><ul></ul></li>");
```

`lis.slice(4)` this will select your li elements starting from index 4

`wrapAll` will wrap a wrapper element around all your `li` elements.

Comment: Nice solution, but some explanation on how it works would help to educate the OP and future visitors.

Comment: Have a read of: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Answer (score 1):

As Rory said you cant use a div inside a list (according to html standard) but you can do it like this.

I made one extra empty list and wrapped this with the wrap function of jquery and added a wrapper class. Then I use the index() function to check the position of the element and if the index is 4 or bigger it will be moved to the second list.

```js
$('#list2').wrap('<div>').addClass('wrapper');

$('#list1').children().each(function(){
  if($(this).index() >= 4) {
    $(this).appendTo('#list2')
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>


<ul id="list2">

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

whatever `<li>` is in the wrapper class, need to select all the `<li>`. After selection  apply word-wrap property.

```
.wrapper li{
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this:

```js
$(".the-button").click(function() {
  var val = 123; //Any value you want
  dynamicLi(val);
});


function dynamicLi(val) {
  $(".dynamic-list li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("wrapper")) {
      $(this).find("ul").append("<li>" + val + "</li>");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.no-bullets {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dynamic-list no-bullets">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li class="wrapper">
    <ul class="no-bullets">
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<button class="the-button">Add More</button>
```